# How do Hypervisor, libvirt and host come together to virtualize the system?

Tags: virtual-machine, libvirt, hypervisor

I am not able to understand this hierarchy. Host OS runs on bare metal. Where does libvirt reside ? where does the Hypervisor reside ? Is libvirt a necessary lib in the creation of a VM or is it just a better abstraction to the core kernel APIs that provide the the service of creation of VMs? what is the libvirt equivalent in windows that is used by Virtualbox ? Does Hypervisor have any role to play in the scheduling of host OS applications or is it just another process handled by the Host OS. These are a few questions that confuse me. Can anyone explain this in a straight manner ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. Host OS runs on bare metal - Yes
2. where does the Hypervisor reside? - It is a software layer on Host OS
3. Where does libvirt reside? - It is another API layer on the Host to indirectly interface with the hypervisor.
4. Is libvirt a necessary lib in the creation of a VM or is it just a better abstraction to the core kernel APIs that provide the the service of creation of 
   VMs? - Standard abstraction
5. What is the libvirt equivalent in windows that is used by Virtualbox ? - Libvirt can be used to interact with VirtualBox.  Libvirt is known to work as a client (not server) on Windows XP (32-bit), and Windows 7 (64-bit).
6. Does Hypervisor have any role to play in the scheduling of host OS applications or is it just another process handled by the Host OS. - Just another process

References: http://virtualbox.guru

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Can you elaborate more on 4th and 5th points ?